# Как создать веб-службу в Web Developer?

Tags: visual-studio, веб-программирование

Создать веб-службу в Web Developer, отображающую результат суммы двух чисел

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сначала идете сюда: [Пошаговое руководство. Создание и использование веб-службы ASP.NET в Visual Web Developer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8wbhsy70.aspx) и выполняете по шагам все действия по созданию веб-службы.

Вместо того, что написано в руководстве подставляете свои функции. Конкретно надо добавить метод System.Web.Services.WebMethod

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
public double AddTwoNumbers(double one, double two)
{
    return one + two;
}
```

и обработчик нажатия кнопки

```
protected void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    localhost.Add wsAdd = new localhost.Add();

    AddLabel.Text = "Sum = " + wsAdd.AddTwoNumbers(1, 2).ToString();
}
```

Ну, и соответственно переименовать все файлы, методы и т.п. и добавить нужные элементы интерфейса.